# ETH Mainnet deployment: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds

Tags: tokens, ether

"Migrations" -- Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!.

Error:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:75:1)
    at Migration._load (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:61:1)
    at Migration.run (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:218:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:258:1)
    at Object.run (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:221:1)
    at Command.run (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:167:1)
```

truffle-config.js

```
mainnet:{
  provider: function(){
    return new HDWalletProvider(
      process.env.MNEMONIC,
      `wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
    )
  },
  gas: 4000000,
  timeoutBlocks: 2400,
  gasPrice: 15000000000,
  confirmation: 2,
  network_id: 1
}
```

How can increase timeout and block number limitations in truffle-config.js ?

Comment: the timeout wont help, once you signed the tx and sent it out, it is there forever and anyone can execute it

Comment: I think the transaction is already submitted to the network. But didn’t got a response in the defined time but that does not revert the tx , it is submitted and can be mined at anytime after sending it.